# Disabling Wifi on Windows 10/Surface Pro4 programatically?

Tags: c#

I have a Surface Pro 4 that is being used in a medical environment and we would like to be able to disable to WiFi on the device when certain applications are running. Is this possible?

Disable is a relative term and as long as the device can't communicate over the wifi, even if technically active, that would meet the requirements. I wasn't able to find any way to do this though.

We could disable Wifi completely but would prefer to have it as an option for the users of the device when the specific applications aren't running.

The application in question is written in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [`Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.radios.radio.aspx) class by calling [`SetStateAsync(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.radios.radio.setstateasync.aspx).

There's a full example available at [Microsoft's GitHub page](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/RadioManager/cs), here's a snippet:

```
private async void SetRadioState(bool isRadioOn)
{
    var radioState = isRadioOn ? RadioState.On : RadioState.Off;
    Disable();
    await this.radio.SetStateAsync(radioState);
    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsRadioOn");
    Enable();
}
```